# SignalR/CORS conflicting web.config requirements

Tags: webforms, cors, asp.net-web-api2, signalr

I'm working on a website that has been around for about 3 years.
It has the website, ASP.Net Web Forms, and the Web API 2.
The site is on one domain (http://localhost:54555) and the API is on another (http://localhost:54666/)

For the past 3 years the site and API have been working together just fine.
I've been tasked with implementing SignalR.
I've managed to get the basics working - I can register users to their groups.
But I noticed in Chrome developer tools (F12) that I wasn't actually using WebSockets when I expected it to be.

After some investigation I found that adding this to the site's web.config file would fix my problem ... and so it did.  Here's what I added to the web.config file;

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="40960" targetFramework="4.5.1" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Whilst this resolved my SignalR problem I'm left with a new problem but for now I thought I'd try reducing the above to this just to see;

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
```

Unfortunately that did not improve anything.

So the problem I now face is this, the calls to the Web API are now failing with the message;

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
```

I don't know even how to go about Googling for this.  Is it a CORS issue?  Is it a SignalR issue?  How can a simple enough looking setting have such an impact on the behaviour of the site?

The only thing I've noticed so far is that the size of one of the cookies is different when this setting is changed.  The cookie in question is called "ClientLogin" and when I can call the API successfully it is 244 in size and when I can't call the API successfully it is 182 in size.  This feels like a potential area to investigate but again, I'm not sure what I should be trying to look for.

Any and all help appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

Add;

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
```

... to the Web API web.config also.